# How to enable PDO on AppServ on windows?

Tags: mysql, pdo, appserver

I am trying to create an app fir the first time using PDO and when i

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBname', 'user', 'pass');
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '<div class="errorMSG">Failed to connect to database. Please try to refresh this page in 1 minute. However, if you continue to see this message please contact your system administrator.</div>';
    echo '<br /><br />' . $e->getMessage();
    exit();

}
```

ofcourse i have change pass user and DBname to the correct once but i have get an error 
could not find driver

So with few searches i found out that i need to enable pdo_mysql but i can't seems to find out where do I do that and how?
Can some one please help me with how to enable this and/or get this to work on my local machine. I have windows 7.
I can't find where is my php.int is located.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look into the [PDO installation section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) of the PHP manual.

It depends on the OS of your machine. If you compile php yourself, and you wish to install the MySQL PDO driver, then you should add the [`--with-pdo-mysql`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) config option before compiling PHP.

On a windows machine, just enable those two extensions...

```
extension=php_pdo.dll <- only if below php 5.3
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

...in your `php.ini` and restart your app server. The `php.ini` should usually be located in your php directory. Where it is located depends on where you've installed php.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am closer to the truth i guess but still problem is not solved. php.int never existed and it was php.int-recomended so i renamed it to php.int and i removed the semi-colen that was before both of the lines you stated. I have restarted my appache and it did not work. it stiill give me "could not find driver" the other option is (--with-pod-mysql) where do I add this and how? My OS is Windows 7     thanks

Comment: Forget about `--with-pdo-mysql` on windows. If you work on windows, you just have to enable the two extensions stated in my answer in your `php.ini`. Try a `phpinfo();` to see which drivers are currently enabled, there should be a PDO section.

Comment: Okay, I am looking at my phpinfo and here is what I see PDO, PDO Drivers enabled are sqlite, sqlite2, I am runing PHP 5.2.6 as of now. so i enabled both of these extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll.

Comment: It _should_ work if both extensions are enabled. Check your apache error log if it encounters errors while restarting your apache, maybe a DLL isn't located where it should be.

Comment: Looking at the log then only thing that failed twise today is PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0 I don't know if this is the problem or part of it?

Comment: `exif` is needed for working with images. Disable this extension if you don't need it and see, if the error behaviour changes.

Comment: That did not work. I actually found the file and placed it there. But i am still having the same issue. so I installed a newer version of AppServ which has php 6.0 so this should have solved the probolem but unfortunatly the problem still exists!

Comment: Change your `php ini` and see if this has any effect on `phpinfo();`. My guess is your php installation doesn't read the `php.ini` you're editing. Maybe check `c:\windows\` if there is another `php.ini`, then work with this one.

Comment: It finally worked after i installed the newer version  and added extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in to my php.ini file because it never existed there. Thanks