# Trying to connect PDO on a local server

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to connecting PDO on my local server. I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and have AppServ installed. In a php document I use the following code for connection:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'password');
?>
```

But the code turns out to be an error: **Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\AppServ\www\a.php:2**

I checked phpinfo() and it shows that sqlite and sqlite2 are the only two databases installed in PDO. So how can I install MySQL PDO?

Comment: You don't have PDO installed. Try with <?php phpinfo(); ?> and see if you have PDO

Comment: your PHP install is missing the mysql driver. that's the long and short of it. either it's not activated, or simply not present.

Comment: [How to install pdo_mysql on Windows](http://www.tothepointsolution.com/site-blog/article/how-to-install-pdomysql-on-windows)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231676/how-to-enable-pdo-on-appserv-on-windows.

Comment: @bksi: if pdo wasn't installed, then you'd get an unknown object error.

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231676/how-to-enable-pdo-on-appserv-on-windows

Comment: I ment PDO mysql driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. I just removed the semicolon in the php.ini file for MySQL and it works! The default location of php.ini file is in C:/Windows/.