# Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object i

Tags: websocket, symfony

when i try to connect to 127.O.O.1/Mysite this error occured can any one help me please ??

Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object in C:\
\PdoSessionHandler.php on line 439

Comment: show some code and explain what you want to accomplish and maybe someone will want to help you. Also, I'm fairly sure that your error has nothing to do with either websockets or symfony

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, read the StackOverflow's guidelines like: [What topics can I ask on StackOverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :-) then update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The line in error is pointing to this function:

*vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php*

```
 private function beginTransaction()
    {
        if (!$this->inTransaction) {
            if ('sqlite' === $this->driver) {
                $this->pdo->exec('BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION');
            } else {
                if ('mysql' === $this->driver) {
                    $this->pdo->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED');
                }
                $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
            }
            $this->inTransaction = true;
        }
    }
```

which is

```
 $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
```

So definitely you should check your config files and enable database drivers as well as make sure you have `pdo` php extension is enabled in php.ini

from command line check if your pdo modules installed:
`php -m|grep pdo`

> pdo_mysql
>
> pdo_sqlite

or

`php -i|grep pdo`

> API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql,mysql pdo_mysql
>
> pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock
>
> pdo_sqlite

It seems you are on windows server from your paths so [look here to enable pdo extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231676/how-to-enable-pdo-on-appserv-on-windows#15231855) , depending on your php installation